# How to check the logged in users session and if they are logged in authenticated?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, razor-pages

I have a identity validation problem I have a HTML and CSS I like to display for people logged in with a ticket number but whenever I start the application after I've closed it as a user logged in I always return as a logged in user with invalid ticket number.

```
<ul class="navbar-nav justify-content-end">
                        @if (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                        {
                            <li class="nav-item pt-4">
                                <a class="nav-link" aria-current="page" href="/mina-sidor/">Mina sidor</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item pt-4">
                                @Html.ActionLink("Logga ut", "Logout", "Authentication", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "btn btn-primary" })
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item pt-4 px-1">
                                <p>Inloggad som <br /> <strong>@User.Identity.Name</strong></p>
                            </li>
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            <li class="nav-item pt-2">
                                @Html.ActionLink("Logga in", "Login", "Authentication", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "btn btn-primary" })
                            </li>
                        }

                    </ul>
```

HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated -> returns true always unless I manually log out.

I've tried Request.IsAuthenticated -> same here.

How do I handle that this return false when the website is closed or it has timed-out?

Answer (score 1):

Have you a github or other repo to see your code?

Is the User.Identity.Name filled?

If your authentication system is based on cookie, exiting from the application the cookies aren't deleted/removed.
So you need to verify if there are still there.

By default ASP.NET is configured for *Session cookies*.
These cookies are not persistent and don't survive if you close your browser.

But if you have a persistent cookie with an expire time, like:

```
   theCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddHours(1);
```

your session will survive to browser closing action.

If your authentication system is based on *Session storage* or *Persistent storage* check it via `F12 - Application - Storage` data.

Comment: User.Identity.Name is filled. I see , it could explain my situation. If i were to delete my cookie on application close that would do the trick? @NicolaBiada

Comment: Yes, I think so.

Comment: Ahune, please confirm the answer if it is ok for you. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This didn't solve my problem. @NicolaBiada

Answer (score 0):

With a page that was shared between two separately running applications, with different validation, I used the following code:

```
@{
    if (Context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) {
        <div id = "QuestionForm" >
            @Html.Partial("_questionFormPartial", Model)
        </div>
    } else
    {
        <p>
            This Request may only be done by an employer who is logged in or staff.
        </p>
    }
}
```